# How to send mails and append them to IMAP with PHP using ProtonBridge?

Tags: php, email, ssl, phpmailer

How to send mails and append them using protonbridge?
I get how to send them with php mailer I did so for Yandex but idk how to do this using protonbridge.

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    $mail->IsSMTP(); $mail->Mailer = "smtp"; $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
    
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE; $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    
    $mail->Port = 1025;
    
    $mail->Host = "127.0.0.1"; 
    
    // [...] subject, mail, mailto, setfrom etc.
```

Proton is configured to use SSL but STARTTLS can also be used, I just dont know how. I keep getting:

```
Connection: opening to ssl://127.0.0.1:1025, timeout=300, options=array() 2023-05-24 19:16:30 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [SMTP.php line 389] 2023-05-24 19:16:30 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [SMTP.php line 389] 2023-05-24 19:16:30 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://127.0.0.1:1025 (Unknown error) [SMTP.php line 389] 2023-05-24 19:16:30 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2023-05-24 19:16:30 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

It's something with SSL or TLS and I don't know what I need to do for it to work.
How do I actually set this up?

Comment: Have you considered reading the error message? It says "certificate verify failed", which means that either your SMTP traffic is being redirected, you're connecting to the wrong server, or the server has an invalid/misnamed/expired cert. This is covered in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure). Your question has nothing to do with IMAP (which PHPMailer can't do), but look at [the PHPMailer gmail example code].(https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps#L91).

Comment: @Synchro it is something with protonbridge, I have sent mails correctly to normal providers but proton bridge is different. The above is correct as per protonbridge and docs. Both run locally, is there anything that might cause this? Do I need https on the php server?

Comment: Well, the obvious thing (which I should have mentioned) is that you're trying to use TLS when connecting to `127.0.0.1`, and it won't be publishing a certificate that matches that, hence the error. I suggest you disable encryption altogether by not setting `SMTPSecure` at all, and setting `SMTPAutoTLS = false`. There is no security risk when connecting to localhost without encryption as your traffic never hits the network.